# Let $n \in \Bbb N_{>1}$. Prove that if $n$ divides $(n − 1)!$, then $n$ is composite.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I realize I should use contradiction here, so that I could use Euclid's Lemma and find something, but I'm still struggling, anyone help please?

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea.

Take a look at what happens if $n$ is prime:

Assume $n$ is prime. If $n$ divides $(n-1)!$, all of its factors must be represented in the factorial somewhere. Since it's prime, it only has 1 factor (itself). Thus, the term $n$ must directly be in the expansion of the factorial. This is a contradiction, since all the terms of the factorial must be less than $n$ by the definition of the factorial. Hence, our assumption was wrong, and $n$ is composite.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** By Wilson's theorem , $(p-1)! + 1$ is divisible by $p$ if and only if $p$ is prime.

Hence $(p-1)! $ is never divisible by  a prime $p$.

Can you complete it now ?

For more information :

> [Wilson's Theorem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Wilson%27s_Theorem)

Comment: My favorite proof of Wilson's Theorem: If $G$ is a finite commutative group with identity $1$, let $K$ be the product of all the members of $G.$ Members of $G$ that are not their own inverses will cancel out in pairs so $K$ is the product of the members of $H=\{g\in G:g^2=1\}$.... If $p$ is prime then multiplication mod $p$ on $G=\{1,...,p-1\}$ is a finite commutative group, and $H=\{1,p-1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $p:= n$ is prime.

If $p$ divides $(p-1)!$ then by Euclid's lemma:

$p|(p-1)$ or $p|(p-2)$ or.........$p|(p-(p-2))$ or $p| (p-(p-1))$.

Impossible since $p >(p-1)$, $p >(p-2)$......,$p>1$, a contradiction .

Hence $n$ is composite.

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive is

> If $n$ is prime, then $n$ does not divide $(n-1)!$

which is a direct consequence of Wilson's theorem.